# Python statement always being executed assitance

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, logic

I have the following the condition statement:

```
if (sc == 'Both') and (fc == 'True') or (bc == 'True'):
     do this
if (sc == 'Front') and (fc == 'True'):
     do this
if (sc == 'Back') and (bc == 'True'):
    do this
```

The problem is that the second and third clause work as expected,however, if the sc equals both and both fc and bc are false this statement still executes, and I don't know why.

Comment: Python interpreter disagrees. I suspect you are missing something. `>>> ('Both' == 'Both') and ('False' == 'True') or ('False' == 'True')`
 `False`

Comment: Wait... Are you using strings (`'False'`) or booleans (`False`)?

Comment: the python here does not do that. Please elaborate how are you setting the values.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
if ((sc == 'Both') and (fc == 'True')) or (bc == 'True'):
     do this
if (sc == 'Front') and (fc == 'True'):
     do this
if (sc == 'Back') and (bc == 'True'):
    do this
```

I think you meant

```
#                                     or binds weaker than and so it needs brackets
if (sc == 'Both') and ((fc == 'True') or (bc == 'True')):
     do this
if (sc == 'Front') and (fc == 'True'):
     do this
if (sc == 'Back') and (bc == 'True'):
    do this
```

You can `and` and `or` are weaker that any operation on numbers so this is also correct:

```
if sc == 'Both' and (fc == 'True' or bc == 'True'):
     do this
if sc == 'Front' and fc == 'True':
     do this
if sc == 'Back' and bc == 'True':
    do this
```

Comment: I think if the values are sc="Both", fc=bc="False" , then the first example of yours also should not come under the if clause.